# Dynamically print spaces/tabs in python

Tags: python-3.x

have a scenario

df has 5 rows

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    print ("\t", i, "Time")
```

need the output to look like

```
 0 Time
      1 Time
           2 Time
                3 Time
                     4 Time
```

How do we make python add the tabs depending on the counter value?
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can multiply the tab by i like so: `print ("\t" * i, i, "Time")`

Answer (score 1):

You could try multiplying of string which would give **i** no of tabs:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    print ("\t"*i, i, "Time")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple change:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    print ("\t"*i, i, "Time")
```